# Fetching in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a Country class,

```
public class Country implements java.io.Serializable
{
private Integer countryId;
private String countryName;
private boolean status;
private Set<State> states = new HashSet<>(0);
..
..
(getters and setters)
}
```

A State class,

```
public class State implements java.io.Serializable
{
private Integer stateId;
private Country country;
private String stateName;
private boolean status;
..
..
(getters and setters)
}
```

How can i fetch only those states whose status is true by writing a function for fetching Country class, i.e

```
public List<Country> getCountryList() 
{
try
{
List<Country> countryList = new ArrayList<>();
Criteria crit HibernateUtil.createCriteria(Country.class,"country").add(Restrictions.eq("status", true));
crit.addOrder(Order.asc("countryName"));
List<?> list = crit.list();
Iterator<?> iterator = list.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) 
{
Country country = (Country)iterator.next();
countryList.add(country);
}
return countryList;
}
}
```

What changes do i need to make in the above function so that if i fetch the set of states from country object, i get only those states whose status is true.?

Comment: Hibernate will not do that, it doesn't make any sense/circumvents the entire purpose of ORM.  You can add a `@Where` restriction on the `Set<State>` on the actual Country model to restrict the contents of the collection.

Comment: You can't. The states of a country are the states of the country. Not **some** states of the country. If you want to get **some** states of a country, you need a query which queries for states.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out this may work for you.

```
public class Country implements java.io.Serializable
{
private Integer countryId;
private String countryName;
private boolean status;
```

> @Where(clause="status=true")
>
> private Set states = new HashSet<>(0);

```
..
..
(getters and setters)
}
```

Comment: But this will always store states whose status is true in the Set. There may be a situation where i might want to see all active and inactive states of a country. Isn't that a valid test-case.? @Mahesh